# Save exact cursor position in the line

Tags: vim, macvim

I am looking way to make Vim save my exact cursor position when I exit it or switch between buffers.

I have the following configuration in my config:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
  \ exe "normal g'\"" |
  \ endif
```

It only returns the cursor to the beginning of the line where my cursor was, but not the position of the cursor in it; i.e. my cursor returns to the beginning of the line, not where it was in it.

Is there any way to bring back the exact position of the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet seems to be a variant of the one found under `:help restore-cursor`, which works the way you want:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") && &ft !~# 'commit'
  \ |   exe "normal! g`\""
  \ | endif
```

The difference is your use of `g'` ("g then single quote") versus their use of `` g` `` ("g then backtick"):

- the former jumps to the beginning of the line marked with marker `"`, just like `'a` would jump to the beginning of the line marked with marker `a`,
- the latter jumps to the exact location of marker `"`, just like `` `a `` would jump to the exact location of marker `a`.

See `:help mark-motions` and, more specifically, `:help g'`.

Comment: This helps and really brings the cursor back to the exact position. But only if I exit Vim, when I switch between buffers the cursor goes back to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Looks like
```autocmd BufEnter * silent! normal! g`"```
helps.